# How to make an exception for mathematical boldface in smallcaps header?

Tags: math-mode, header-footer, small-caps

I have smallcaps headers. With sections names and chapter and the left and right marks. In some cases I have vector bold in the section names. This creates a problem for headers of these sections. The smallcaps conversion of the section name does not go well with the vector bold (it changes the case) and renders is as a small letter instead of a capital one. For example the image below shows the header rendering for `\section{Magnetic Field $\vb{B}$}`. Can we make an exception for mathematical expressions in the headers? Any other ideas how to implement this?

[image: section title with vector bold]

[image: section header]

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[tracking=smallcaps]{microtype}

\usepackage{relsize}

 \usepackage{fancyhdr}

 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
 \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
 \markboth{#1}{}}

 \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{ #1}}
 \fancyhf{}

 \fancyhead[RO]{\textsc{\smaller{\MakeLowercase\rightmark}}}


 \fancyhead[L]{\smaller\thepage}

\makeatletter
\fancyhead[RE]{\if@mainmatter \fi \textsc{\smaller{\MakeLowercase\leftmark}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{physics}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{one}
\section{Magnetic Field $\vb{B}$}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could declare a separate math version for headers, or just use a different symbol.

Comment: I, personally, would be confused to see the same vector called B in the section title and **b** in the text. Are you sure that’s a good idea?

Comment: @davislor that is precisely the problem. The text has bold B from \vb{B}  whereas the header, due to makelowercase and smallcaps has converted the capital boldface B it to smallcase bold b

Comment: No, there is no typo. I meant \vb{B} in the main text. Which is not displaying correctly in the header.

Comment: Ah, I see now, pardon. Was not able to reproduce your bug and got confused.

Comment: @Davislor you have a 2022 latex  release :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a current LaTeX you get

[image]

if updating is not an option, you can use `\MakeTextLowercase` from the `textcase` package.

Note `\textsc` has no effect  on math, but you need a version of MakeLowercase that skips math

Comment: Ok, I will update and try textcase as suggested, PS: I had forgotten about 22 release!

Comment: I just changed the header to all caps (removing `\textsc` )using `\MakeTextUppercase` to have consistency with capital bold math. Thanks for the suggestion